# How to select tr elements that have more than 4 children with XPath?

Tags: xpath

The XPath expression `root.xpath('//table//tr')` can get all the `tr` elements in root.
Now I want to select all `tr` that have more than 4 children. How to write the expression?

I have tried `//table/tr[count(child::)>4]` and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, try this :

```
//table/tr[count(child::*)>4]
```

or simply :

```
//table/tr[count(*)>4]
```